# What is the shortest logic to get back an input (say A) from an output of an OR gate (bitwise OR), if we know another input and the final result?

Tags: architecture, logic, bitwise-operators, logical-operators, boolean-logic

Suppose I know an input **B** and the output **A+B** (A **OR** B) what is the shortest logic that I can apply to get the other input **A**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't necessarily get all the bits

The logic table for an or gate is

```
A  B  A+B
0  0   0
0  1   1
1  0   1
1  1   1
```

So if you know that A+B is 1 and B is 1, you cannot know what the value of A is.